# How can I find the DynaLoader mapping of module names to opaque pointers?

Tags: perl, shared-libraries, libdl

According to the docs on [DynaLoader](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/ext/DynaLoader/DynaLoader_pm.PL)

> **`dl_unload_file()`** Dynamically unload `$libref`, which must be an *opaque 'library reference'* as returned from `dl_load_file`. Returns one on success and zero on failure. This function is optional and may not necessarily be provided on all platforms.

So `dl_load_file` returns those opaque reference. But what if my file wasn't loaded by explicitly calling `dl_unload_file` how do I then find out those references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find those references by using the [following variables, as documented in the source](https://metacpan.org/release/perl/source/ext/DynaLoader/DynaLoader_pm.PL#L147)

```
@dl_shared_objects  = ();       # shared objects for symbols we have 
@dl_librefs         = ();       # things we have loaded
@dl_modules         = ();       # Modules we have loaded
```

However, matching them to the name of the library remains an exercise to the user though it seems as if they're index-sensitive into those three arrays. You can do it like this,

```
my %db;
foreach my $i ( 0 .. $#DynaLoader::dl_librefs ) {
  $db{$DynaLoader::dl_modules[$i]} = {
    dl_shared_objects => $DynaLoader::dl_shared_objects[$i],
    dl_librefs        => $DynaLoader::dl_librefs[$i],
    dl_modules        => $DynaLoader::dl_modules[$i]
  };
}
```